# How to introduce amp's <amp-script> in Wordpress function.php and load it in the amp page

Tags: amp-html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSpiC.png)

Can you help me?

Comment: Are you asking how to enqueue a script for a specific page?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. If you want to create an AMP web worker and run script, here's how it's done:

```
<amp-script layout="container" script="script-async" data-ampdevmode>
<p>Web worker DOM to be placed on your page (HTML goes here)</p>
</amp-script>
```

And that part goes to `functions.php`:

```
<?php add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>

/* Add amp-script component from ampproject CDN */
<script src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-script-0.1.mjs" async="" custom-element="amp-script" type="module" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script id="script-async" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
//Your JS code goes here.
</script>

<?php });
```

If your question is how to add `amp-script` component in head of your page then you can use official AMP [plugin for wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amp/) and all components will be added automatically if they are needed.